# What are the differences between inheriting nativesdk and BBLASSEXTEND=nativesdk?

Tags: sdk, yocto

What are the differences between

```
inherit nativesdk
```

and

```
BBLASSEXTEND="nativesdk"
```

in a bb recipe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `inherit nativesdk`, recipe is made only for nativesdk purpose and must be named `nativesdk-myrecipe.bb`.

If you want a normal recipe to be also used in nativesdk, you have to extend it by using `BBCLASSEXTEND="nativesdk"`.

Details can be found in [Yocto manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-classes-nativesdk).